# How do I format an image for display on a Cisco SPA 303

Tags: cisco, telephony

In the [manual](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/429481/Cisco-Spa509g.html?page=53) it says I have to create a 128x48 bmp image with 1-bit per pixel, but when i upload it to the phone, it merely displays a full black image.

I've tried:

- creating the image with gimp, saving it as a 1-bit indexed bmp.
- `convert input.bmp -colors 2 -type Bilevel -depth 1 output.bmp`

the latter produces the following output when calling `identify output.bmp`:
`output.bmp BMP 128x48 128x48+0+0 1-bit sRGB 2c 914B 0.000u 0:00.000`

Which looks completely up to specs to me.

Can someone tell what i'm doing wrong, or give me pointers to debug the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, and then I took a look at the example image they provided in their guide (here: https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/51231/configuring-bmp-logo-spa303-and-spa50xg-ip-phones) by using identify.
Turns out their bmp is BMP version 3.

So I re-encoded my image from a monochrome png using :
"convert test.png -depth 1 -type Bilevel BMP3:test.bmp"
and IT WORKED HALLELUJAH!

So I feel like the 5 hours I wasted on that are completely justified.
Peace out.

Comment: You sir, are my hero!
-depth 1 doesn't work for me, though. The image remains 8-bit, i'll probably give this another go next friday!

Comment: for me it was:
`convert test.png -depth 1 -monochrome -colors 2 -type Bilevel BMP3:test.bmp`